# How to: Certification or Whitelist of application exe and msi installer

Tags: c, visual-c++, whitelist

Windows will always tag as unsafe. Written in C+ Visual Studio 6.
Can someone please outline steps to whitelist or digitally certify an exe packed in MSI. I have read that you can digitally sign in later versions of Visual Studio.  This is written is VS 6. This is not managed code - their is no layer between the software and low level access.  Is their a list for Microsoft to test the software as well as other virus vendors?

Comment: signtool.exe comes with the Windows SDK. To sign code and installers you will need to purchase a signing certificate. Signing code does not test the software or verify that it does not have viruses. All it does is put a digital signature on the code so a user can verify where it comes from.

Comment: I agree with @JosephWillcoxson. He has not posted the error message he gets, so it might also be because his environment prevents the application from being run, because it isn't whitelisted by his organization.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.